# REACT - Como pego no array somente itens que tem"sim" em disponível? Utilizando um botão!

Tags: javascript, react

```
export default function App() {
  const [produtos, setProdutos] = useState([]);
  const lista = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Livro",
      preco: 32.99,
      estoque: "sim"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: "Tenis",
      preco: 132.99,
      estoque: "sim"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: "Monitor",
      preco: 689.99,
      estoque: "nao"
    }
  ];

  const disponiveis = () => {
    const contemProduto = lista.filter((p) => p.estoque === "sim");
    if (!contemProduto) {
      {
        "AQUI APARECE QUE NÃO TEM NO ESTOQUE"
      }
    } else {
      {
        "AQUI APARECE O NOME DO PRODUTO"
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Produtos em Estoque</h1>
      <ul id="list">
        {lista.map((produto) => (
          <div className="conteudo">
            Nome: {produto.nome} - Preço: {formatarPreco(produto.preco)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="informacoes">
        <button onClick={() => disponiveis()}>Verificar Status</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Meu caro, deixa eu explicar uma coisa: o voto negativo, nessa plataforma, reduz a reputação de quem dedicou tempo a te dar uma resposta. Se você vota negativo em qualquer resposta que não seja a que você espera, você estará passando uma mensagem para as pessoas: não respondam minhas perguntas, ou vocês provavelmente perderão reputação.

Comment: Quanto à minha resposta, o que eu te disse é verdade. Você, na pergunta, não disse o que você quer fazer com os produtos filtrados -- mas a variável ```contemProduto``` já tem uma array dos produtos com a propriedade ```estoque``` igual a ```sim```. Se você quer ajuda, você tem que explicar o que você pretende fazer com essa informação (sua pergunta só fala que você quer "pegar", mas você já pegou).

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, a variável `contemProduto` já contém um array dos produtos disponíveis. Você só precisa escolher a forma como quer exibir.

```
const disponiveis = () => {
    const contemProduto = lista.filter(p => p.estoque === "sim");

    //A variável acima já é a array dos produtos disponiveis. Você pode ver assim:
    console.log(contemProduto)

    //Ou, para exibir só os nomes, você pode fazer:
    const nomes = contemProduto.reduce((acumulado, atual) => acumulado += atual + ", ")
    alert(nomes)
}
```

Na real, você já pegou os valores, só falta decidir o que quer fazer com eles (e não explicou na pergunta).